# Sphere Point Picking in Cartesian coordinates

Tags: random, coordinate-transformation, rotation

I have a vector $\vec{A}(x, y, z)$.

Now I want to rotate the vector randomly (`x` by `ϕ`, `y` by `θ` and `z` by `ψ`) in the 3D plane in the Cartesian coordinate itself.

Is there any way to do that?

I want to pick points randomly on a sphere so that they are uniformly distributed.

Comment: What is the "sphere point picking" problem, in this context?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html

Comment: If you want to pick points randomly on a sphere so that they are uniformly distributed, then please say so. Currently it is said in a difficult to understand way. There is a method for it on the page that you linked to. Please also see the function [RandomPoint](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint.html).

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based on `RandomPoint` as pointed out by C.E.

Define the following function that generates the random points given a 3D vector and sample size.

```
pts[A_List, n_] := 
 RandomPoint[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, Sqrt[A[[1]]^2 + A[[2]]^2 + A[[3]]^2]], 
  n]
```

Example:

```
data = pts[{1, 2, 3}, 1000];
ListPointPlot3D[data]
```

[image: example output]